# Combining the two polar Navier-Stokes equations into a single PDE using vorticity and streamfunction

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-fields, fluid-dynamics, cylindrical-coordinates

I am starting with the following reduced form of the Navier-Stokes equations in **polar coordinates**.

$$u_r\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial r}+\frac{u_\theta}{r}\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial\theta}-\frac{u_\theta^2}{r}=-\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial p}{\partial r}+\nu\left(\nabla^2u_r-\frac{u_r}{r^2}-\frac{2}{r^2}\frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial\theta}\right)$$
$$u_r\frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial r}+\frac{u_\theta}{r}\frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial\theta}+\frac{u_ru_\theta}{r}=-\frac{1}{r\rho}\frac{\partial p}{\partial \theta}+\nu\left(\nabla^2u_\theta+\frac{2}{r^2}\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial\theta}-\frac{u_\theta}{r^2}\right)$$

Using the definition of the **streamfunction** $\psi$ in polar coordinates, $$u_r=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial\theta},\;u_\theta=-\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial r}$$ and the **vorticity** $\omega$ $$\omega=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r u_\theta)-\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial\theta}=-\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial r}\right)-\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial\theta^2}$$ I need to combine the equations into the following **single** PDE.

$$u_r\frac{\partial\omega}{\partial r}+\frac{u_\theta}{r}\frac{\partial\omega}{\partial\theta}=\nu\nabla ^2\omega$$

The instructions for this process are given in this [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40065-013-0081-2).

1. Take the derivative of the $r$-component with respect to $\theta$. (I think this means $\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$.)
2. Take the derivative of the $\theta$-component with respect to $r$.
3. Combine these "appropriately" and note that the pressure terms vanish.

I started this by rewriting both equations, and solving for the pressure term before taking the derivatives.

$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial p}{\partial r}\right)=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(...)$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{1}{r\rho}\frac{\partial p}{\partial \theta}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(...)$$

However, I'm unclear on what to do with the $r$-derivative of the $\theta$ pressure term so that the two cancel out when subtracted. Similar issues occur when expanding the other derivatives. I've tried expanding out each term in terms of derivatives of $\psi$ but it gets very complicated. Is there an easier strategy to try and combine these into the desired form?

**Addendum:** I thought of this after posting the question.

Comparing the original two equations with the final goal, I noticed that the first two advective terms have a counterpart with the vorticity. That is there is a $u_r\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial r}+\frac{u_\theta}{r}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\theta}$ group where $\phi$ is either velocity or vorticity. The same is true for the Laplacian $\nabla^2\phi$.

My current thought is that writing the remaining terms out in terms of the streamfunction $\psi$, taking the respective derivatives, and then subtracting them will be zero. I am currently working on that but not having much success.

**Addendum 2:** 9/21/23 After doing some more reading, I think what the authors of the paper actually intended was for the derivatives of $u_r$ and $u_\theta$ to be calculated normally and inserted into the advective and diffusive terms using the stream function $\psi$. I am still looking to see if I can identify different terms and I've noticed a lot of cancellations but haven't been able to resolve it yet fully. However, the pressure terms do not appear to cancel out.